# Usb adapter doesn't work in dual boot!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, bluetooth, adapter

I work right now with a dual boot pc, windows 10 and installed a while ago ubuntu 20.04. I use 2 adapters, a Wifi and a bluetooth one! They were working great on Windows, then when i first used ubuntu, they were working just fine! After the first time using Ubuntu, i switched to windows and none of these two now works!
Any explanation?

Comment: Is this a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: i have tried that! But it doesn't work!

Comment: Let's gather some data: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Does this help? https://plumthegoodman.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/01/29/125746